# Writing custom condition inside .withColumn in Pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, databricks, pyspark

I have to add a customized condition, which has many columns in .withColumn.
My scenario is somewhat like this. I have to check many columns row wise if they have Null values, and add those column names to a new column. My code looks somewhat like this:

```
df= df.withColumn("MissingColumns",\
    array(\
    when(col("firstName").isNull(),lit("firstName")),\
    when(col("salary").isNull(),lit("salary"))))
```

Problem is I have many columns which I have to add to the condition. So I tried to customize it using loops and f-strings and tried using that.

```
df = df.withColumn("MissingColumns",condition)
```

But this condition is not working. May be because, the condition I have written is of data type String.
Is there any efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unpack your list inside the array as follows:

```
columns = ["firstName","salary"]
condition = array(*[when(col(c).isNull(),lit(c)) for c in columns])
```